# Starting wifi scan while in background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk, wifi

Im working on a navigation app that requires active wifi access (due to its connectivity to a hardware device using wifi), my trouble is that when the app is in the background the wifi scanning interval is dropping considerably and at some point the app will scan for wifi connectivity only every 5 minutes.

Any ideas of how it would be possible to trigger a wifi scan more often?

Any lead appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you can use reachability class provide by apple and use Timer and set Time with 5 mint and ever 5 mint check status of WiFI connectivity

Comment: @NitinGohel you shouldn't need to wrap it in a timer. It should fire when the reachability status changes.

Comment: @Sheni Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Go for `Reachability.h` class and use `kReachabilityChangedNotification` defined in the class.

Comment: Thanks Gents, we are familiar with reachability, however reachability wont trigger a wifi scan, it would just let us know weather we are connected or not.. which is not really solving our issue :(